# In VHDL when is the right time to use a Process statement?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I'm going through the phases of learning VHDL for the second or third time now. (this time armed with a very good and free [e-book](http://www.freerangefactory.org/) ) and I'm finally starting to "get" quite a bit of it. Now I'm learning about behavioral styles and the process statement and most of it makes sense. However, I've read in many places that processes are to be avoided except for in certain cases. I mean, in theory can't everything be implemented in data-flow instead of behavioral?

When exactly should it be obvious that a process statement should be used?

Comment: Where have you read that processes should be avoided?  They're pretty much fundamental IMHO!

Comment: @MartinThompson not necessarily avoided, but easily abused I guess? People familiar with traditional programming tend to use process statements when they shouldn't be because it provides something almost procedural

Answer (score 7):

The process statement is extremely useful, in what situations have you been told not to use them?

There are many different cases where you would use a process statement, I'll outline a few of these below:

One of the most common usages of the process statement (for synthesis) is to describe logic which is synchronous to a clock signal, for example a simple counter that increments every clock cycle when not in reset could be described as:

```
DATA_REGISTER : process(CLOCK)
begin
  if rising_edge(CLOCK) then
    if RESET = '1' then
      COUNTER <= (others => '0');
    else
      COUNTER <= COUNTER + 1; --COUNTER is assumed to be of type 'unsigned'
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

As your designs grow more complex you will inevitably implement a state machine at some point, this will employ one or more processes depending on the style of state machine you choose to implement.

For behavorial code you can use processes in conjunction with wait statements to generate test vectors or to model the behaviour of a real system. Here's a really basic example of a 100MHz clock generator taken from one of my testbenches:

```
architecture BEH of ethernet_receive_tb is  
  signal  s_clock : std_logic := '0'; --Initial assignment to clock kicks off the process.
begin
  CLOCKGEN : process(s_clock)
  begin
    s_clock <= not s_clock after 5 NS;
  end process CLOCKGEN;

...
```

You can also describe asynchronous logic with processes, in this case you need to include all signals which are read in the process in the sensitivity list and you need to make sure that any outputs are always defined to avoid inferred latches.

```
IF_ELSE: process (SEL, A, B)
begin
  F <= B; -- Default assignment
  if SEL = '1' then
    F <= A;
  end if;
end process;
```

Hopefully you can see that the process statement is very useful and that you will use it in many different situations. I hope this answered your question!

Answer (score 4):

Process blocks are your friend.

They provide a way of saying "This block of code is related. It's inputs are X,Y,Z and it drives A,B,C". The inputs are documented by the sensitivity list (unless it's a clocked process in which case it should be in your comments). If anything else drives the same signals then you'll get warnings, errors, X's in simulation (depending on your tools). Whatever you get it's pretty obvious.

Personally I would be quite happy writing multiple processes in a single entity, but everyone has their styles. For example, if I have multiple pipe-line stages, each stage is a process. If I have parallel non-interfering paths each will be in a separate process. By doing it this way the code is structured in small, easy to read blocks. Small simple logic synthesizes into small fast blocks (in general).

You could view my style as using them as lightweight entities.

Answer (score 2):

In synthesisable code, processes are *required* any time you need to keep information from one clock cycle to another.  "To store state" in the jargon.

(Note that a process can implied by code such as

```
d <= q when rising_edge(clk);
```

)

If non-synthesisable code, processes are useful for getting events to happen in a particular order:

```
p1: process
begin
   data <= "--------";
   WE <= '0';
   wait until reset = '1';
   wait until processor_initialised = '1';
   assert ACK = '0' report "ACK should be low!" severity error;
   data <= X"16";
   WE <= '1';
   wait until ACK = '1';
end process;
```

---

Most of my code has a single process per entity.  Each entity does some useful, well-defined and small-enough-to-be-testable task